# Android - Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy is not valid; is your activity running? android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I've gone through lot of posts about this issue before I post my own question , and Im still not able to find any solution to it , in fact I don't even know where the problem is !

I keep getting this crash everyday on my crashlytics dashboard ( only for few users ) . Unfortunately its only giving me the crash infos but not showing which line or class is causing it , and other thing is that 100% of devices affected are using Android 13 & most of them are samsung devices.

I understand that this is most likely happening because Im trying to show a dialog after execution of a background thread, while the Activity is being destroyed , so I checked all my code and I've added to each dialog the condition below.

`if(!YourActivityName.this.isFinishing())  { //show dialog }`

Kindly help me to reproduce this exception.

My firebase log

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView (ViewRootImpl.java:1764)
android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView (WindowManagerGlobal.java:567)
android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView (WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
android.app.Dialog.show (Dialog.java:521)
com.TruckLogics.Utility.TransparentProgressDialog.show (TransparentProgressDialog.java:55)
com.TruckLogics.CommonController.DashBoardActivity.showProgress (DashBoardActivity.java:4541)
com.TruckLogics.CommonController.DashBoardActivity.isSupportTicketRaised (DashBoardActivity.java:4317)
com.TruckLogics.CommonController.DashBoardActivity.access$6700 (DashBoardActivity.java:224)
com.TruckLogics.CommonController.DashBoardActivity$50.onResultSuccess (DashBoardActivity.java:4401)
com.TruckLogics.ServiceClass.SiteDownUpChecking$1.onResponse (SiteDownUpChecking.java:51)
retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0$retrofit2-DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1 (DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run (Unknown Source:6)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:942)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8757)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:571)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn more about how your exception happens, then I suggest you add some firebase logging. The most usefull will be about the lifecycle states of your activity, and whether the dialog was shown or not. This will give you additional information on where the problem is. For example, maybe you are showing a dialog from the background - this is forbidden.

If you are showing your dialog from the background thread, then depending on how its done, it can cause various problems. Consider redesigning this part, ie. you may use Intent to send information to your activity that a dialog should be shown. Then if the activity is shown it will show this dialog in its own context, if its hidden then it will show and again - display safely your dialog.

I'am not sure if:

```
if(!YourActivityName.this.isFinishing())  { //show dialog }
```

would help in all scenerios, what if your activity is in background  and you are showing your dialog?

Comment: Can you check my firebase log ?

Comment: @KarthigaGanesan its possible that your Activity is already destroyed once your retrofit connection ends. I use to fix such cases with interface (implemented by Activity) which is used by background task - it is stored in the background task in a WeakReference. When I need to make a call on it, I get a ref from WeakReference and use it only if it is non-null. It will be null when Activity would be destroyed. Its not perfect, but one way of dealing with such problems.